# Service Locator - Disadvantages over DI

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, service-locator

Both of these achieve same goal of decoupling. But just different patterns.

1.) What exactly are disadvantages of Service Locator over DI?
 A couple of them if I got it right.

- Needs Container. So you component needs a Container code
- Unit testing is hard.

2.) What exactly are the advantages of SL over DI?

- Kind of provides encapsulation of dependencies.
- No need to explicitly advertise the dependencies.

3.) When to use what? (DI/SL). Any real life examples?

This has been discussed in several thread. But there is no real concise answer for this.

Comment: Perhaps that's because, as you said yourself, **there is no real concise answer.**

Comment: I guess someone who used it in the real project could answer this. They may have seen something that we cannot simply think out of patterns

Comment: Answer: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the Dependency Injection and Service Locator patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557781/whats-the-difference-between-the-dependency-injection-and-service-locator-patte)