# Unity container - resolve object which always same constructor parameter

Tags: c#, unity-container

I want to have only one instance of TestClass in my code. This class needs string parameter. Question is that, how can I register this object to unity container with string parameter once in UnityConfig class and then resolving this object everywhere in code? I tried it like this but during resolving I am getting exception.

This is my class:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass(string str)
        {
            message = str;
        }

        private string message;

        public string Message
        {
            get => message;
            set
            {
                message = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my `UnityConfig` class:

```
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        private readonly UnityContainer unityContainer;

        public UnityConfig()
        {
            unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
            unityContainer.RegisterType<TestClass>(new InjectionConstructor("Injected string"));
            var unityServiceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(unityContainer);
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => unityServiceLocator);
        }
    }
```

I am resolving it like this:

```
var serviceLocator = (UnityServiceLocator)ServiceLocator.Current;
var unityContainer = (UnityContainer)serviceLocator.GetService(typeof(UnityContainer));
var testClass = unityContainer.Resolve<TestClass>();
```

and then I am getting this exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type = "SpotFinder.ViewModels.TestClass", name =
>   "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be
>   constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
>
> ---
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving SpotFinder.ViewModels.TestClass,(none)
>   Resolving parameter "str" of constructor SpotFinder.ViewModels.TestClass(System.String str)
>   Resolving System.String,(none)

I tried also register like this:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<TestClass>(new InjectionConstructor(
                new InjectionParameter("Injected string"))
            );
```

Comment: Why not just make a static Class object initialized with the constructor? wont that be easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get new instance of `UnityContainer` using `GetService(typeof(UnityContainer))` that doesn't have `TestClass` registration, so it give you a exception during resolve. Just use directly serviceLocator to resolve `TestClass`. It looks like this:

```cs
var serviceLocator = (UnityServiceLocator)ServiceLocator.Current;
var testClass = serviceLocator.GetService(typeof(TestClass));
```

And registration:

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
// Configure only one instance of testclass
unityContainer.RegisterType<TestClass>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("Injected string"));
var unityServiceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(unityContainer);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => unityServiceLocator);
```

P.S. I don't suggest you to use `ServiceLocator`, you can look some his [advantages/disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557781/whats-the-difference-between-the-dependency-injection-and-service-locator-patte)