# C#. Implementation of MediatR library

Tags: c#, mediatr

I have several questions regarding implementations of MediatR.

`public class RequestHandlerWrapperImpl<TRequest, TResponse>` has `Handle` method:

```
public override Task<TResponse> Handle(IRequest<TResponse> request, IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task<TResponse> Handler() => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>>()
        .Handle((TRequest) request, cancellationToken);

    return serviceProvider
        .GetServices<IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>>()
        .Reverse()
        .Aggregate((RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse>) Handler,
            (next, pipeline) => () => pipeline.Handle((TRequest) request, next, cancellationToken))();
}
```

So it uses `GetRequiredService` method to find a service when we use for example a `sender.Send(new CreateItem());` command.

Sorry if my assumption is not correct, I don't have to much experience in this aria

1. Can `GetRequiredService` be considered as example of service locator that is anti pattern?
2. If it is true why this lib is popular?
3. Is there any other choice to avoid service locator in this lib implementation?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review and understand the guidelines and rules of this site *before* asking a question.  This post has a number of issues:  It is asking many questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things,  soliciting opinions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions, and asking for recommendations https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: 1) yes it can 2) why not, this is not shown to user, and while service locator can be considered an antipattern "it is ok when you know what you are doing" 3) may be but  in general it is not worth the hustle. P.S. such questions can be considered off-topic at SO (especially the second point which is clearly opinion-based).

Comment: The first question, which is the only unambiguously answerable question here, is also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557781/whats-the-difference-between-the-dependency-injection-and-service-locator-patte